# Extrair Posts do Feed Linkedin

Tags: javascript, api

Estou pesquisando na documentação do LINKEDin uma maneira de extrair os Posts de determinada empresa. É possível fazer isso ?

Não estou encontrando métodos.

O mais perto que cheguei foi nesse link: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages

Mas não tem nada parecido com Feed, semelhante ao que tem no Twitter e Facebook.

Eu tento rodar uma URL direto no Browser conforme a documentação com o ID da Empresa e mostra um erro:

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Unknown authentication scheme",
  "requestId": "MJYSLQZZXX",
  "status": 401,
  "timestamp": 1448970119372
}
```

Comment: A nova versão da API do linkedin está cheia de limitações. Eu desisti por exemplo de conseguir as conexões de uma pessoas. Estava muito burocrático.

Comment: Eu li no SOen que não é possível extrair dados do Feed, mas era uma pergunta de um ano atrás. Então pensei que tivesse atualizado. Mas que essa API é bem limitada, isso é mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você leu na resposta do SOen está correto, não é possível mais fazer isso. No [Blog Oficial do Linkedin](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes) você pode ver as mudanças que foi realizado em maio de 2015.

Está sendo comum as empresas restringirem as funcionalidades de suas API's, seja por uso abusivo ou algum problema. Isso pode ser visto com as demais, como a do Facebook, Google, Outlook, etc. Quem utiliza esses serviços por alguns anos, sabe que vem acontecendo esse tipo de restrição.

O Linkedin disponibiliza [o console](https://apigee.com/console/linkedin?apig_cc=1) com os endpoints de sua API. É muito útil para saber o que pode ou não ser requisitado.

Uma possível solução seria você tentar o [Programa de Parceiros](https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs) do Linkedin e ele diz isso sobre o programa:

> A parceria com a LinkedIn fornece funcionalidade adicional à API, acesso a dados, o aumento dos limites de chamada e suporte dedicado. Leia mais sobre nossos vários programas de parceiros e casos de uso e veja se é corresponde para a sua aplicação. As candidaturas só são aceitos quando sentimos que eles estão fornecendo valor aos membros, desenvolvedores e LinkedIn.

Answer (score 0):

Este erro é porque, ao colar a url no browser, você fez uma chamada GET na API sem passar nenhum token de autorização.

Para realizá-la, basicamente você precisa registrar a sua aplicação no LinkedIn e, assim, receber um token de acesso para passar no header de suas requisições.

Sem isso, não tens "permissão" de acessar a API restful deles. E, logicamente, receberá sempre um status HTTP 401.

Eles expressam o passo-a-passo neste link: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2